# Liferay 7.1 DPX with JBoss 7.1 EAP

Tags: jboss7.x, liferay-7

my doubt is about Liferay DPX project with JBoss, in this manual https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028810012-Installing-Liferay-DXP-on-JBoss-EAP mencion unzip Liferay DPX .war on #JBOSS/standlone/deployments, when a download that .war i have dependencies errors and when i place basic Liferay project i haven't errors however i put on browser 127.0.0.1 an Forbidden error show it.

I don't know if structure inside of /deployments/ROOT.war is like that [Basic Liferay 7.1 DPX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emfNv.png)
or like this
[Liferay 7.1 DPX .war content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmuhT.png)

Haven't log error from add on this post but i hope someone used Liferay with JBoss and can clarify this doubt.

Thanks for your time! Greetings

Trying resolve my doubt about Liferay and JBoss project